# Metrics are not an option when creating an Azure alert rule

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-alerts

I can see the BGP metric I want to monitor in Azure but if I try to create an alert, there are no options for metrics after selecting the resource.

Here is an example of the metric:
[image: screenshot1]

After selecting the virtual hub as the scope, these are the only signals available to select:
[image: screenshot2]

Any suggestion as to why no metrics can be selected?

Thanks!

Edit: When creating a custom log, I also encounter this error:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I have created virtual WAN with Hub like below:

[image]

Created BGP peer:

[image]

In metrics:

[image]

To alert your BGP you can use kusto query in custom log search like below:

```
AzureMetrics
| where MetricName == "BGPAvailability"
| summarize by Average, bin(TimeGenerated, 5m), Resource
| render timechart
```

[image]

[image]

Alert has been triggered successfully like below:

[image]

Refer this [github](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/expressroute/monitor-expressroute.md) link to more in detail:

[image]

Additionally, You can use condition of All administrative operation like below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply. Interestingly, I encounter this error when I try to create the Custom Log Search: "BadArgumentError- 'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'AzureMetrics'"

Comment: I am encountering an error with the way you described. I'll upvote your replies for the effort but I can't mark it as resolved yet as the error persists. I am starting to suspect a RBAC issue...